# Getting rust analyser Error in Anchor?

Tags: anchor

I am trying to set up an anchor workspace but I constantly get this error when I create a new repo or do `anchor init project_name`. I am not getting this error with my previous anchor repos.

Please help i have wasted tons of time for this error.

[image: VS Code Image]

Comment: umm possibly run `cargo build` / `cargo run`

Comment: That work's for sure I am dumb at rust if I don't get rust analyser working

Comment: ha not at all, we were all there once. Will post as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the required crate isn't installed yet.

Try running `cargo run` or `cargo build`